# SslStream, узнать длину Read данных до выделения памяти?

Tags: c#, .net, производительность

У `SslStream` есть метод `Read`, который параметрами принимает инициализированный массив байт (назовём его буферным), офсет и максимальное количество байт, которые могут быть записаны в буфер, а могут быть и не записаны, если их недостаточно во входящем потоке. Во многих протоколах обмена данными мы не всегда знаем точный размер следующего пакета или архитектура приема-передачи построена на абстрактном "конвейере", в котором буферы выделяются сразу под максимально возможный размер пакета, он может быть 12 байт, а может быть 12 000 байт. Поэтому приходится инициализировать буфер большего размера (с запасом, который зачастую превышает в сотни раз реальное количество байт во входном потоке), что пагубно влияет на расход памяти и производительность приложения.

**Вопрос**: каким образом грамотно и с уклоном на производительность можно переопределить или каким то другим образом получить сначала размер пакета (например считав его в какой то временный буфер меньшего размера) или сам временный буфер (чтобы потом просто заменить ссылку на основной буфер)?

Comment: А что вам, собственно, мешает считать сначала длину сообщения?

Comment: А зачем вы хотите подстраиваться под размер сообщения? Поскольку это сеть, то сообщение в большинстве случаев будет фрагментировано, так что и не надейтесь прочитать его без цикла за один присест. Заведите буфер любого размера, и читайте в цикле до тех пор, пока не получите нужное вам количество данных.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, можно ли как то перед записью в буфер достучаться до lsass и получить размер уже расшифрованного tls пакета?

Comment: @VladD, для увеличения производительности и уменьшения аллокаций больших буферов.

Comment: @user222250 зачем вам вообще размер **пакета**? Вам нужен размер **сообщения**.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, размер расшифрованного сообщения можно как то узнать? Или lsass декодирует пакеты и сразу пишет в буфер SslStream?

Comment: @user222250 а вы его, этот размер, передаете или нет? Если передаете - то надо его просто прочитать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, извините за задержку с ответом, размер не передаётся в сообщении.

Comment: @user222250 а как тогда вы определяете границу сообщения?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, по отсечке SslStream, он не ждёт когда придёт весь размер буфера, он сам каким то образом возвращает целостное сообщение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, т.е. За размер сообщения видимо отвечает сам протокол tls, а SslStream его подхватывает.

Comment: Оптимизация выделения массива при чтении из сети? Вы экономите на спичках при старте космической ракеты.

Comment: @Align: Есть подозрение, что вы пользуетесь таки потоковым протоколом, и если только ваш сервер не находится в той же подсети, вам ничто не гарантирует, что сообщение примется за один присест, или что в пришедшем блоке данных не будет сразу несколько сообщений.

Comment: @VladD в той же подсети тоже ничего не гарантируется. Любой достаточно большой пакет дойдет частями.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну это да, но надо же как-то объяснить ТСу наблюдаемый им эффект?

Comment: @VladD в качестве объяснения - можно предложить записать со стороны сервера два сообщения подряд, и после этого попробовать прочитать данные со стороны клиента, в буфер заведомо большего объема. Они вычитаются как одно большое сообщение - и это уберет иллюзию наличия "отсечки". Вот только вопрос старый, и топикастер, скорее всего, давно его решил :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Или не решил и забил? Вопрос всё же о микрооптимизации.

Comment: @VladD если микрооптимизировать - то в том случае, который упомянут в вопросе - архитектура приема-передачи построена на абстрактном "конвейере" - выгоднее использовать один реюзабельный буфер размером с максимальное сообщение :) т.е. все и так хорошо, ничего менять не надо

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну да. Не зря, кстати, в `stream.Read` кроме длины можно указывать оффсет. Так что можно просто заказать один огромный буфер, и читать в него, запоминая последнюю записанную позицию. (Но непонятно, что делать, когда буфер таки закончится.)

Answer (score 0):

Я выделял 1024 байта, и в цикле увеличивал размер буфера(Array.Resize())

Comment: А причину минуса писать не принято?

Comment: не минусовал. Вы разместили очень неполный поверхностный ответ, вероятно причина минуса в этом.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: на собственном опыте, о чем я написал

Comment: @Serg, данный вариант не подходит, просто потому что если мы получаем 12 килобайт - у нас будет 12 аллокаций, а метод Resize тупо создает новый массив и копирует в него старый.

Comment: @user222250, GC.Collect() спасает от мусора)

Comment: @Serg , дело не в немедленной сборки мусора, тема для обсуждения производительности, если каждый раз вызывать коллект - медленнее некуда...

Comment: Ну тогда точно не подойдет. Надо на протокол смотреть. Imap, например, передает размер письма.